# IIS Web Core Issue - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: iis-7.5

I am getting this following issue. What can be possible reason.

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: That error is related to your web.config file.  You will only have one web.config file per directory, but you may have multiple web.config files stuffed into various subfolders so you may be dealing with more than one file.  i would start by renaming web.config to web.config.bak and see if you still get the error.  Then you can start picking apart your web.config file.  Typical web.config problems includes trying to load a module that doesn't exist or maybe a simply typo in the file (web.config files are XML based).

Answer (score 0):

For me all I did was delete the file web.config . However, my serverside was ColdFusion which has in-built functionality to do a deepsearch of web.config starting from the parent directory to the internal ones. so I had a web.config file in one of the inner directories.

Comment: The only time ColdFusion "looks" for a web.config file is within the Web Connector configuration wizard (WCConfig).  IIS is the application looking for a web.config file on each request.

Comment: @JasonHolden thank you for clarifying my point.